# Making a bot that takes surveys with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hey guys I'm trying to make a bot that takes and answers surveys but i cant find any info or similar stuff that will be helpful I'm not that good with python but if anyone knows a bot that's similar to this just comment.

Comment: **Welcome to StackOverFlow, @Naydawin !** If anyone has the answer to this, they will post it as an answer, rather than as a comment. And, could you elaborate? _making a bot_ is no _easy_ task, and requires a lot of research.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the **https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/**,
if you have any expecific question about selenium or how does it work you can make another question.

Comment: I mean, from that you can start coding and investigating on how to find the html elements and how to execute javascript and things like that, your question is not very especific tho